# How to update model class?

Tags: ios, swift4

### My viewController

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate{

private var actors = [Actor]()


@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Welcome"
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    downloadJson()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}


func downloadJson() {

    let reponseValue = NetworkOpertions.sharedInstace.getMethod(){ (fetchValue)-> Void in

        if  fetchValue != nil {
            print("MY fetch Value:",fetchValue)

            do {
```

> Here how can i get data from model class

```
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)

            }

        }
    }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return actors.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ActorCell") as? ActorCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    cell.nameLbl.text = actors[indexPath.row].name
    cell.DOBLbl.text =  actors[indexPath.row].dob
    cell.countryCell.text = actors[indexPath.row].country



    if let imageURL = URL(string: actors[indexPath.row].image) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            if let data = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imgView.image = image
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}

}
```

### My modelClass

```
import UIKit

class Actors: Codable {
let actors: [Actor]

init(actors: [Actor]) {
    self.actors = actors
 }
}

class Actor: Codable {
let name: String
let description: String
let dob: String
let country: String
let height: String
let spouse: String
let children: String
let image: String

 init(name: String, description: String, dob: String, country: String,  height: String, spouse: String, children: String, image: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.dob = dob
    self.country = country
    self.height = height
    self.spouse = spouse
    self.children = children
    self.image = image

  }

  }
```

### My netwokOpertions

```
//

 import UIKit

 class NetworkOpertions: NSObject {
// For Singletone class
static let sharedInstace = NetworkOpertions()

private override init() {

}

 private var actors = [Actor]()

func getMethod(OnCompletion:@escaping (Bool)-> Void) {


    guard  let url = URL(string: FETCH_API_URL)else {return}

    let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url){
        (data,response,error) in

        if let err = error {
            print("We have an Api call error:\(err)")
            return
        }


        if let data = data {
            print("This is Data:", data)
            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let downloadedActors = try decoder.decode(Actors.self, from: data)
                self.actors = downloadedActors.actors
                OnCompletion(true)
            }

            catch let err{
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                OnCompletion(false)

            }

        }
    }
    session.resume()

  }


  }
```

My question is : In my networkOpertions class i am updating model class, and want to use the value inside viewController How?? If i simply reloading self.tableView.reloadData() its showing nothing.is there any other way to use it

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let reponseValue = NetworkOpertions.sharedInstace.getMethod(){ (fetchValue)-> Void in

    if  fetchValue   {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.actors =  NetworkOpertions.sharedInstace.actors
            self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much .it's working for me .But one doubt is it a good practice coding practice??

Comment: it's the standard practice